# how to accumulate 2D array elements in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have 2D array as:
`Array(Array(1,1,0), Array(1,0,1))`
and I would like to accumulate values over column so my final output look like 
`Array(Array(1,1,0), Array(2,1,1))`

If this is 1D array, I can simply use 'scan' but I'm having trouble with using scan in 2D array.

can anyone help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
val t = Array(Array(1,1,0), Array(1,0,1)) 

val result = t.scanLeft(Array.fill(t(0).length)(0)) ((x,y) => 
  x.zip(y).map(e => e._1 + e._2)).drop(1)

//to see the results
result.foreach(e => println(e.toList))
```

gives:

```
List(1, 1, 0)
List(2, 1, 1)
```

The idea is to create an array filled with zeros (using [Array.fill](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Array$.html#fill[T](n:Int)(elem:=%3ET)(implicitevidence$9:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Array[T])) and then scan the 2D array using that as an accumulator. In the end, `drop(1)` gets rid of the zero-filled array.

*EDIT*:

In response to the comment, this solution works for a matrix of any size. The `zip` function takes care of element-wise addition.

*EDIT 2 (Step by step explanation)*:

You already know about `scan` or a one-dimensional array. The idea is essentially the same.

1. We initialize the accumulator with *zero*. In this case, zero means an array of zeros. `Array.fill` is used to create an array filled with zeros.
2. Instead of a single addition, we need to add arrays element-wise. This is what the combination of `zip` and `map` do. There are a lot of examples available on the Internet about how these methods work.
3. Finally, we drop the *zero* element using Scala's `drop(1)`. The result is an array of arrays containing accumulated values.

Comment: It worked!. Thanks for your feedback. Is there any better way to modify this so that I can use for arbitrary number of rows and column?

Comment: This solution already works for arbitrary number of rows and columns (of the same size)

Comment: this solution works perfectly fine and I'm totally satisfied with results. since I'm a noob in Scala world, can you elaborate a little bit how your solution is working step by step?

Comment: sorry for late response. thanks for your follow up response. really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Emm, glad it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much the same approach as a 1D array:

```
a.tail.scan(a.head)((acc, value) => 
  Array(acc(0) + value(0), acc(1) + value(1), acc(2) + value(2))
)
```

For arbitrary number (as long as they all have the same number):

```
a.tail.scan(a.head)((acc, value) => 
  acc zip value map {case (a,b) => a+b}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is there any better way to modify this so that I can use for arbitrary number of rows and column?

Comment: This solution is essentially equivalent to mine! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it as for given row `r`, sum all previous rows.

```
val accumatedMatrix = 
 for(row <- array.indices)
  yield array.take(row + 1).foldLeft(Array(0, 0, 0)) {
    case (a, b) => Array(a(0) + b(0), a(1) + b(1), a(2) + b(2))
  }
```

input:

```
val array =  Array(
  Array(1,1,0),
  Array(1,0,1)
)
```

output:

```
1,1,0
2,1,1
```

Instead of summing all the previous rows repeatedly you can improve it to memoize as well.

Comment: I don't think `scan` would reiterate the operation from scratch for every element. Could you expand a little bit about the difference of this solution with the ones using `scan`?